# How to reliably measure code efficiency/complexity/performance/expensiveness in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, performance, time-complexity

My question consists of 2 parts:

1. Is there any good way in C# to measure computation effort other than using timers such as `Stopwatch`? Below is what I have been doing, but the granularity is not great, and the result returned varies every time. I am wondering if there is more precise measure such as CPU operation count so that the result returned can be consistent.

   ```
           Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
           stopWatch.Start();

           //do work

           stopWatch.Stop();

           TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

           Console.WriteLine(ts);
   ```
2. If the alternative approach in 1 is not possible, how can I make the performance test result less variate? What are some factors that can make the result change? Would closing all other applications running help? (I did try it but there seems to be no significant effect.) How about running the test on a VM, sandbox, etc.?

(After typing the proceeding text I realized that I also have tried the Performance Analysis feature which comes with Visual Studio. The test result seems more coarse because of the sampling method it uses. So I also want to rule out that option)

Comment: What level of "granularity" are you looking for? Also the nature of the inconsistency really depends on what is in "do work" which you haven't told us.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a profiling tool. But you can use `StopWatch` more reliably if you run your tests in a loop multiple times but only take the results of the test if the garbage collection generation stays the same.

Like this:

```
var timespans = new List<TimeSpan>();
while (true)
{
    var count = GC.CollectionCount(0);
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    /* run test here */
    sw.Stop();
    if (count == GC.CollectionCount(0))
    {
        timespans.Add(sw.Elapsed);
    }
    if (timespans.Count == 100)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

That'll give you 100 tests where garbage collection didn't occur. The average is then pretty good to work from.

If you find that your tests never run without invoking a garbage collection then try working out the minimum number of GC's that get triggered and collect your time spans only when that number occurs.

Comment: Hmm.  Real programs garbage collect.  I hear what you are saying, but profiling without allowing GC to occur is not useful unless you also measure the time that the CPU is off doing garbage collection, and how often it does it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Yes and no. Yes real programs have garbage collection and you have to understand if your code has performance issues because of garbage collection. But no for profiling code - you want to understand how a section of code performs so you need to remove all extraneous factors. Otherwise you really can't optimise the code in question properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could query a system performance counter. The [msdn doc for the System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has some examples. With this class you could query "\Process(your_process_name)\% Processor Time" for example. It's an alternative to Stopwatch but tbh I think just using stopwatch and averaging many runs over time is a perfectly good way to go.

If what you need is a higher resolution stopwatch because you are trying to measure a very small slice of cpu time, then you may be interested in the [High-Performance Counter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2635/High-Performance-Timer-in-C).